# problems with the autoload of PHP classes

Tags: php, autoload

I am new to php and I was doing some tests to make an MVC project with php, the problem is that when using autoload to import the classes, php does not recognize them, but it suggests it when using it, this is my code.

composition of folders and files

```
--public
  --index.php
--src
--vendor
--composer.json
--composer.lock
--Router.php
```

composer.json
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4BqV.png)

Router.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaUIv.png)

public/index.php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft4Pi.png)

message error

`[Wed Dec 28 16:40:52 2022] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "MVC\Router" not found in C:\apache\htdocs\test\public\index.php:5`

try to create everything again using composer init and then update by making a change in composer.json but it didn't work.

I also moved the router class to another folder to see if the error had to do with the routes but it gave me the same error, I appreciate your help in advance

Comment: where are you invoking the [autoloader](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)?

Comment: the autoload is in the vendor folder

Comment: yeah you need to invoke it, see the link. namespacing !== autoloading

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand your answer

Comment: read the linked docs, tldr; you have to add `require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` in your code for composer autoloading to work.

Comment: but I already added the class path to composer.json, should I also add the path in the class that I want to export?